# How to create partitions in SSAS tabular 1400 compatibility?

Tags: ssas-tabular

We are implementing `SSAS 2017` tabular mode for our reporting needs. I am trying to create partitions in one of the tables. I built a SQL query for the partitions. While the SQL query works fine on the database, it throws an error when validating using the partition manager. I tried to use the query editor but couldn't get much. I tried to check the query using advanced editor in query editor which says there are no syntax errors.

Following is the query I am passing:

```
SELECT
[Account - Company Code],
[Additional 1],
[Additional 2],
[Additional 3],
[Additional 4],
[Additional 5],
[Additional 6]
FROM dbo.[Table Name]
WHERE [Date - Accounting] >= '2012-01-01' AND [Date - Accounting] <= '2012-01-31'
```

The error I get in Query Editor is

> Expression.SyntaxError: Invalid identifier.

Please help me sort the issue.

I read on MSDN that in a model of 1400 compatibility the partitions need to be created using Power Query M language but I am unable to retrieve any examples to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the tutorial to do this. Posting it here so that anyone can refer to it in the future.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/tutorials/aas-lesson-10-create-partitions